# Versions Maven Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, versions-maven-plugin

How can I add the Versions-Maven-Plugin to my Eclipse projects ??

I tried the `Add Plugins` menu option but it doesn't seem to be able to find the plugin.

Comment: Why do you need the version plugin to be added to a project ? For which purpose?

Comment: To check for version updates to the dependencies. I'm working with beta jars mostly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the [versions maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/usage.html) into the reporting part of your pom to create appropriate reports about dependency updates.

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
      <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
          <reports>
            <report>dependency-updates-report</report>
            <report>plugin-updates-report</report>
            <report>property-updates-report</report>
          </reports>
        </reportSet>
      </reportSets>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

You can not install the versions-maven-plugin in Eclipse, cause the version-maven-plugin is a Maven plugin and not a Eclipse plugin. But not an bad idea.

Comment: The above snippet can also be found on their website: http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 29):

To check maven plugin version in eclipse:

- Click Window –> Preferences –> Maven –> Installation . It will show you installation window with Maven version.

Comment: I'm surprised this answer has so many upvotes, it's in fact completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Pyves because when people search how to check maven version, this question comes first and this has their answer.

Comment: Try searching: how to check maven version in eclipse